# No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s)

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using Xcode 4.5.2 and have a project which cannot be compiled for an iPhone running iOS 6.0.1 though other projects compile fine with the same settings as shown in the picture below.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

[image: Architectures in Xcode]

Comment: Are you using a third party lib?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're probably using some third party lib that doesn't yet support armv7s architecture. You can just remove armv7s from your settings. Your app will still be able to run on iPhone 5 although it might not be taking full advantage of the new architecture.

Comment: do we have to remove it from "Architectures" or "Valid Architectures"?

Comment: @Satyamsvv In my case the third party lib was open source, so I just added armv7 support in it instead of disabling it in the main project, if I remember well. I believe I changed both architectures and valid architectures

Answer (score 5):

If on XCODE 12 just goto Build Settings search for VALID_ARCHS. Under the User-Defined section select Valid Architectures and click Delete.

[image]

Comment: this solves my error "No such module" for one of my cocoapods module on xcode 12.5 when ran on simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Set valid architecture for iOs simulator to  armv7 and armv7s.( simulators are 32 bit ).
 for device set to arm64 (64 bit all new ios device).