# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 Swift Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, architecture, x86-64, undefined-symbol

The error code from my compiler

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMOAuth2KeychainCompatibility", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthStateMigration_bdf842e92d17b12b5f020e0e721bd017.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_OIDServiceConfiguration", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_f05654be6d1b2af59ab6df426a0c4eb9.o)
"_OIDResponseTypeCode", referenced from:
  -[GIDSignIn authenticateInteractivelyWithOptions:] in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_f05654be6d1b2af59ab6df426a0c4eb9.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_OIDAuthorizationService", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_7b83cc27af8929ec7e4c9760d73a0f31.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_OIDURLQueryComponent", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_f05654be6d1b2af59ab6df426a0c4eb9.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_OIDAuthorizationRequest", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_f05654be6d1b2af59ab6df426a0c4eb9.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorizationWithEMMSupport in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_7b83cc27af8929ec7e4c9760d73a0f31.o)
  objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_7b83cc27af8929ec7e4c9760d73a0f31.o)
 (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorizationEMMChainedDelegate, _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorizationWithEMMSupport )
"_OIDOAuthTokenErrorDomain", referenced from:
  ___46-[GIDAuthentication refreshTokensWithHandler:]_block_invoke in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_7b83cc27af8929ec7e4c9760d73a0f31.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_OIDIDToken", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDGoogleUser_2bdd4a676c033bc6ca21970e75d9159c.o)
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization", referenced from:
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorizationWithEMMSupport in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_7b83cc27af8929ec7e4c9760d73a0f31.o)
 (maybe you meant: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorizationWithEMMSupport, _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorizationEMMChainedDelegate )
"_OIDOAuthErrorResponseErrorKey", referenced from:
  +[GIDAuthentication handleTokenFetchEMMError:completion:] in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_7b83cc27af8929ec7e4c9760d73a0f31.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMKeychain", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthStateMigration_bdf842e92d17b12b5f020e0e721bd017.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_OIDAuthState", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_7b83cc27af8929ec7e4c9760d73a0f31.o)
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have already tried everything to make It work again and everything I read on stack overflow from other posts who face a similar issue

-reinstall pod
-update pod
-new podifle
-removing target
-deleting derived data
-cleaning project
-restarting simulator
-restarting Xcode

i don't even know what I have changed to make this problem appear, never faces this issue before

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The error came by me accidentally deleting code in the pod file, which I was not aware of.

deleting the pod and moving it back in did not help

halt helped was

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

W/o sample project we can only guess what did you make wrong.

So my guess...
If you updated to Xcode 12 - go to project settings, scroll to the bottom `User-Defined` section and remove `VALID_ARCHS` setting. If you don't have it there - then my guess was wrong and I wish you good luck :D.

**UPD:**
I found [same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64333027/1135154)

Comment: I cannot find the VALID_ARCHS in my project